# How to open "BigTIFF" files?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, graphics

I'm looking for some software that would open BigTIFF files on a mac - ones that are 6GB or bigger. (I'm not opposed to writing some code to do so, but I'd prefer a prewritten solution.)

Does macOS have any built-in software to handle this sort of thing? If not, are there any commonly-used external programs or libraries that I could employ?

I just need to view the images and be able to zoom in - I don't need to edit them.

**NOTE:**

Just to be clear, I am not wanting to view large TIFF images. I am specifically referring to bigTIFF images. If you are not familiar with these, please refer to http://bigtiff.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, macOS includes the Preview app which can open large TIFF images.

By default, the Preview app is located within your Applications folder.

The Preview app actually offers a lot of functionality, including:

- opening images and PDFs
- editing images and PDFs
- signing documents
- sharing files
- annotation

For more details, see this [page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201740).

If I've misunderstood your question, please feel free to clarify it.

Comment: Are you sure Preview would handle >6 GB TIFF images? For me, it looks like Preview loads the whole file into memory. And what do PDFs and signing have to do with bigTIFF?

Comment: @Monomeeth - Based on your answer, I'm guessing you're not super familiar with bigTIFF images (which is totally normal - I had never heard of them until two days ago.) There's some info about them here: http://bigtiff.org/

Comment: @techraf To be honest I haven't opened a TIFF image larger than 6GB, but I do regularly open TIFF images in the order of 3.5GB. Preview often looks like it stops responding (even to the point the spinning beachball disappears) but then after a few minutes the image appears fine. Zooming in/out also works, after the initial zoom which takes a little while. Of course, the amount of RAM and type of storage you have will have a big impact on response and open/save times.

Comment: There's a technical difference between 3.5 GB and 4.5 GB TIFF.

Comment: @mchen.ja I was starting to suspect that, as I just noticed you rolled back my edit to your question. Also, I did think there was a 4GB file size limit in terms of TIFF image sizes, although that may only be a limit with Adobe Photoshop (which will work with 6GB+ images but won't save any larger than 4GB). I also know many image viewers don't support more than 30,000 pixels in either direction (height v width). Thanks for the link to bigtiff.org (I suggest you edit your question in order to clarify exactly what you're trying to do).

Comment: @Monomeeth - I found a link to a zip file of some example files here: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/bigtiff/BigTIFFSamples.zip (which is linked at the bottom of the page here: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/bigtiff.html). I can verify that preview wasn't able to open the example images.

Comment: @Monomeeth - hmm... I thought my question was clear. I welcome any edits that you'd like to make to clarify the question, as long as it's clear that I'm looking for something to open BigTIFF files (rather than simply large TIFF files.)

Comment: @mchen.ja Thanks for the link. Do you happen to know where I can get a sample BigTIFF file that's over 6GB in size? The other samples are very small and I've found a solution that can open them, but I have my doubts how well it would work with files of the size you're talking about.

Comment: @Monomeeth I don't, unfortunately. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Update for Sonoma: Preview does open the bigTIFF sample files.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from 2023: the command line utility `convert` from ImageMagick was able to convert a BigTIFF file to other formats (such as png)

You can install `convert` / [ImageMagick](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/imagemagick) using Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Graphic Converter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/), my go-to photo and graphic app for many years, handles some tough tasks.

Comment: Graphic Converter is an excellent package, and will no doubt support BigTIFF in time, but as I've discovered as a result of researching the OP's question, _BigTIFF_ is a new file format that isn't readily supported yet. Specifically, BigTIFF is a variation of the TIFF file format which uses 64-bit offsets and supports file sizes larger than the 4GB limit of the standard TIFF format (which only uses 32-bit offsets.